# Android image processing library that facilitates C/C++ processing

Tags: android, image-processing

My ideal image processing library for android just provides a means to load images into memory in a standard format without any extra lossiness as it is loaded from the file/camera and then allows me to painlessly call my own C or C++ routines that operate on that format and finally allows me to save the result in a standard format to a file (possibly with loss, e.g. jpeg) . This seems to be quite different than the approach taken by most android image processing libraries. Is there such a library that has a good reputation?

Comment: Please review the answers carefully, and up vote the ones that helped you. You can also click on the checkbox near an answer to select it as the official answer to your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, [OpenCV](http://opencv.org/platforms/android.html) (Open Source Computer Vision).

Also recommend taking a look at [Tutorial on Using OpenCV for Android Projects](http://www.stanford.edu/class/ee368/Android/Tutorial-2-OpenCV-for-Android-Setup-Windows.pdf).